# Error Invalid resource directory name: "res content"

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I uninstalled Xamarin Form in my solution and installed it again. After the installation when I try to run my android project it giving me error as Invalid resource directory name: "res content" in File: aapt.exe.

aapt file is present in my android-sdk path. Can anyone let me know the solution to resolve this error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Build Action of each of your images should be set to AndroidAsset and not AndroidResource.

Answer (score 0):

I faced like this problem when i remove a xml file from one directory to another by drag and drop.
this problem was solved when i delete that directory and create again directory and xml file. clean the project and build.finally project build successful.

In your case, at first clean the project, copy all file that contain in "content" directory and then delete "content" directory. now create an new directory and paste all copied file. build the project. 
hope it will help you.